# valores multiples variable en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy  realizando  un  programa  en el  cual  se guardan los  datos  de las   personas  tales  como nombre, edad , sexo, telefono de contacto. En la variable  telefono  quiero  que se pueda guardar varios  numeros de telefono por una sola  persona  y no solo uno. por  ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es atraves  de a lo que llaman **multivalued attribute** pero no  se como  se hace la  consulta para poder insertarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En una tabla separada

```
CREATE TABLE Personas
(
  Id int identity primary key, 
  Nombre nvarchar(100) not null,
  Edad int not null,
  Sexo nvarchar(6) not null
)
GO
CREATE TABLE Telefonos
(
  Id int identity primary key, 
  Telefono nvarchar(20) not null, 
  PersonaId int NOT NULL REFERENCES Personas(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Para consultar esta estructura usas:

```
SELECT Telefonos.Telefono
FROM Personas
JOIN Telefonos
  ON Personas.Id = Telefonos.PersonaId
WHERE Personas.Nombre='Andres Perez Lopez'
```